# Using multiple weights for lm() or glm() in R

Tags: r, regression, glm

I want to fit a model in R within which I need to apply two weights at the same time. Let's say my model is `glm(y ~ x1 + male + East_Germany)` where male identifies a respondent's gender and East Germany is also a binary variable checking whether someone lives in East Germany.

Now let's say both females and East Germans are dramatically missrepresented in my data. Assuming that it's not due to a flawed data collection process, I would have to apply two weights. But can I really specify two weights simultaneously like this...? `glm(y ~ x1 + male + East_Germany, weight=c("male_wgt","east_wgt"))`

My thinking was that applying *one* weight to the overall data or the overall model already changes up the whole data structure, but I might be wrong. Let's give you an example:

```
y   x1   male   east   male_weight   east_weight
5   4    0      1      5             2
3   2    1      1      1             2
9   7    1      0      1             1
4   8    1      0      1             1
1   3    1      0      1             1
6   4    1      0      1             1
```

...where `male==1` means "male" and `male==0` is "female" and we assume that both genders should be represented equally (50%), and where `east==1` means "East Germany", `east==0` is "West Germany" and here too, let's assume for reasons of simplicity that both should be represented equally. `y`and `x` are just random numbers.

I'm wondering how I would apply both weights simultaneously, because if I say "let's count row#1 five times so that females gain more weight", I'm at the same time giving East Germany *too much weight* (without having even applied `east_weight`). The reasons is that if we count row#1 five times, we will end up with a new East/West ratio of 6:4. Or am I mistaken?